# very slow bridge detection

Tags: networking, bridge

I have setup some bridge interface with 4 ethernet port. My problem is, when they detect some network topology change, the bridge really need a lot of time to have done it.

Is there any solution, so the bridge can detect topology change faster ?

Comment: So... what OS (if a software bridge), what switch vendor? What model? Are you talking topology change as in a spanning-tree change or simply an access port going up or down?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is spanning tree protocol causing this. You can either disable it and risk bridge loops (your network will be down) or better find how to configure the interfaces to do fast checks (portfast in cisco).

some hints here:
http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps700/products_tech_note09186a00800b1500.shtml

Comment: is it mean, more ethernet port I used in bridge network, it would take longer the process ?

Comment: Portfast disables spanning tree protocol on those ports, which is probably not what you want on bridge ports. Have a look at Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol (RSTP), which takes about 15 seconds or so.

Comment: I would recommend MST above RSTP - it's cross-vendor and ought to be universal for decent switches these days.